# ArcGIS Server Manager requesting log on for every page of web interface, how can I prevent this from happening?

Tags: arcgis-server

The first issue that came up was that the Certificate was not recognized. I saved this to my machine and imported it to all tabs of the Certificate Authority. I also realized that the link being used didn't have the FQDN. When I entered this it seemed to correct the Initial Certificate Error which was thought to be the issue.

As it turns out this wasn't the case. When I log in with the Server Administrator account and I try to go to, for example, the Security Link. It will send me immediately to a log in page and I would have to enter the credentials again to proceed. I was also informed by the Senior Admin who passed on this troubleshooting issue to me that the server was changed and the new license was placed on the machine and this was not the issue before.

How can I rectify this constant having to log in every time a feature is accessed from the Web Interface?

Comment: what version of server are you running?

Comment: ArcGIS 10.4.1 for Server (Linux)

Comment: This isn't a server error so much as a browser issue with a dodgy certificate. You actually have several potential errors, and from the way you've described it, your Server install shouldn't be operational at all. Please [edit] the question to specify how these certificates were generated, and review what steps were taken and in what order, especially with respect to changing servers. You should also include the operating system, and whether a Web Adapter is installed, and on which web server (and OS, if a different server).

Comment: From what I have been able to gather the Server is Red Hat Linux and its the same server for the Web Adapter. Currently it is functional, as user accounts have been created and clients use it to publish their maps. The only issue is the annoying having to log on. This issue was just passed on to me to troubleshoot so I am still gathering more information you request. 
I did import the certificate to my machine and added it to the Certificate Authority and only then did it not show the certificate error using IE11.

Comment: Well as it turns out the time on the server was what was causing the logon page to be redirected every time. It was off by 12 hours hence affecting the timeout. Thanks all